# Testing App on Physical device or semulator

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a flutter App, I have run the code so many times on simulator and even on my smartphone, but after some time when I open the app, it is at the initial stages and after a hot restart the app goes to the final stage(i.e. the changes I've made after that), don't know how to fix the problem.

Comment: So whats the problem?

Comment: Is there any way so that the test App remains upto date? and not need the hot restart each time when I tap on the app icon.

Comment: Detach your device from your computer. You will no longer receive hot reloads :)